# Where can I get an export certificate of customs in India?

Tags: india, customs-and-immigration

I had noticed about the export certificate which allows me to carry goods without paying the duty. But there is a problem, I couldn't know where to get that and do we have pay for that?

Comment: So does it mean that we can obtain the export certificate while returning back to India at the immigration counter and we will not be liable to pay any duty on the gold jewellery?

Answer (score 8):

You dont have to pay for it. Note: This certificate is to be taken *when you're leaving India* so it **helps you on future trips into India**.

It's available in the airport (or whichever international port of departure from India)

Usually - after the Immigration counters and before you proceed for Security checking, there are a couple of counters where White-uniformed Customs officials are seated.

You have to show them the goods - they might even ask for an original bill. You have to fill up a form, which states the price etc, and they stamp and certify it. This is the Export Certificate

Remember to carry it on your next arrival to India alongwith that item.

See more at http://www.immihelp.com/travel-to-india/export-certificate.html

Comment: this is after Check-In. The server/ boxes / parts will have to be checked-in. How / where can I get an export certificate for them? 
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57601/minimize-customs-charge-on-export-import-from-india-to-us-back-for-computer-s