# Obtain Export Certificate from Indian Customs for items in checked baggage before Check-In?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, india, check-in, export-certificate

This talks about a counter after immigration, much after check-in counter.
[Where can I get an export certificate of customs in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16378/where-can-i-get-an-export-certificate-of-customs-in-india)

#### Indian Customs counter at airports in India are typically after Check-In & Immigration counters, How / where can I get Export Certificates for them?

---

Another part of the question I've posted here:

**Customs Duty & Regulations specific to the 'Category of items'**
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57601/minimize-import-customs-duty-on-repair-replacement-pc-computer-server-parts-exp

---

**Traveling with these Items & Packing:**
Items have to be checked-in due to size/ weight & with protective padding in luggage/ suitcase.
[Can I bring my desktop computer as check-in baggage on a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/can-i-bring-my-desktop-computer-as-check-in-baggage-on-a-flight)
[Taking a Desktop Computer Overseas - Options?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/taking-a-desktop-computer-overseas-options)

This talks about packed items in Checked baggage when Importing but not when exporting in Checked Baggage 
[Packed Items at Indian Customs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19027/packed-items-at-indian-customs)

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's advised to carry these items in carry-on, so that they can be inspected, which is why Export Certificates are issued post check-in at immigration.

Of course, as you mention, you might want to check this luggage item, which makes it tricky to present.

In this case, your best bet is to contact the airport and ask them for their Export Certificate, and submit it well in advance of the flight, and ask for where the goods can be inspected at the airport, given that you're checking in the luggage.

For example, Bangalore airport has [instructions for this](http://bangalorecustoms.gov.in/expcerti_instructions.htm), with the Export Certificate form that you fill out, an email to send it to, and phone numbers which you can contact about the process.

Comment: Great. I tried but was not able to find a similar outline for Mumbai airport. Lets see what I can do with this.

Comment: Some Mumbai instructions: http://www.customsmumbaiairport.gov.in/forms/Content.aspx?LinkID=77

Comment: @AlexS let us know if it answers your issue, and if it's Acceptable. I'm trying for hats ;)

Comment: Thank you. I will check on this and get back with you :)